# Unable to integrate admob interstitial for googleplay release

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

This is my first time to be implementing interstitial ads for my android app. And I'm having a problem with the intergration, I've followed the official Google Mobile Ads SDK tutorial but the thing I still don't understand is how to prepare for the initial release? I simply want to set the ads and upload it to the store.

Are there some errors or have I made some misunderstanding ? The ads doesn't even show up.

```
 interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
      interstitial.setAdUnitId("myunitid");

      AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

      interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
      displayInterstitial();

}

public void displayInterstitial() {
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
            interstitial.show();
        }
    }
```

This is the part of the manifest file

```
  <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
            <!-- Activity required to show ad overlays. -->
            <activity
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
                android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

This is what it is my gradle

```
 compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

Comment: Post your manifest file

Comment: I've added additional code from my manifest and gradle.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what josedlujan has told your here are some thing to consider.

```
displayInterstitial();
```

Should be called at a point in the app when it does something interesting or finishes a major action. An example being when the user enters a lot of text and presses done.

```
done.setonClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View v) {
displayinterstitial();
}});
```

And you should handle the scenario when the user is moving to fast or attempting to avoid your ad by pressing backpress or has a slow internet connection.

```
public void displayInterstitial() {
    if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
        interstitial.show();
    }else{
//Do something here that will loadad and show a video, an image or a toast while you wait for your ad to load to then try to show interstitial again. 
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio o Eclipse?

Android Studio:

Add Dependencies

```
dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
    }
```

Add permission inside Manifest!

```
<!-- Include required permissions for Google Mobile Ads to run-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Add this in Manifest too.

```
 <!--This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services.-->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

     <!--Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"                android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

File string.xml

```
 <string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111</string>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm having a test interstitial ad shows up even though, Ive set AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build(); and set my real unit id. Can I upload it to the store?